# After appending inputs to imported DOM element it's becoming disabled

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, append, html-imports

My problem is when I try to append an input box it becomes non-active. I mean I can't put anything into it.

I'm using a HTML-import and I append input into imported element

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
    
    <html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/19enter code here99/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Feedback Form</title>
        <link rel="import" href="background.html">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
    <body>
        <script>
            var link = document.querySelector('link[rel=import]');
            var content = link.import.querySelector('#background');
            document.body.appendChild(content.cloneNode(true));
        </script>
        <div id="email_form">
            <p>E-mail: <input type="email" id="email_from_email" name="email_from_email" /></p>
        </div>
      <script>  
     $("#email_form").appendTo("#maincontent"); //here I append input
      </scrit>
    </body>
    </html>
```

background.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="background.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="background">
        <div class="background" id="menucontent">
            <!--some code here-->
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="background" id="maincontent">
            <!--An input is appendend but I can't put anything in-->
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The element `#maincontent` is not in the main document *index.html*, but in the imported document *background.html*.

So you cannot select it with the jQuery library using `.appendTo( "#maincontent" )`.

Instead you should select it the same way you did with `#background`:

```
var maincontent = link.import.querySelector('#maincontent');
```

*Note:* I don't see why you would like to insert some element in the imported document, that is not rendered. Usually we perform the operation in the opposite direction.